# Enable Health Checks in Spring Cloud Load balancer will not work when using Custom Config

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

Discover Client Properties

```
spring.application.name=load-balancer-client
spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled=false
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
server.port=8081
spring.cloud.loadbalancer.health-check.refetch-instances=true
spring.cloud.loadbalancer.health-check.refetch-instances-interval=2s
```

API App Properties

```
spring.application.name=service-api
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true
```

My Client Load Balancer Configuration Looks like this

```
public class LoadBalancerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ServiceInstanceListSupplier instanceSupplier(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        return ServiceInstanceListSupplier.builder()
                .withDiscoveryClient()
                .withHealthChecks()
                .build(context);
    }
}
```

This is my  Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@LoadBalancerClients(defaultConfiguration = LoadBalancerConfiguration.class)
public class WebClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder builder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }


    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

When I start My Load balancer Client, the rest call fails with the below Error

```
2021-10-12 11:50:48.962  WARN 21664 --- [        Timer-0] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: service-api
2021-10-12 11:50:48.962  WARN 21664 --- [        Timer-0] eactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction : LoadBalancer does not contain an instance for the service service-api
2021-10-12 11:50:48.963 ERROR 21664 --- [        Timer-0] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped
```

I alternatively tried by enabling health check by using only using only below
`spring.cloud.loadbalancer.configurations=health-check` and it results in Same Error

This happens only when the health check is enabled an it works fine `.withHealthChecks()` Uncommented

There is no `@Configuration` Annotation on the custom config class and I have started the registry server, api server and load balancing client in the right order as well
Can someone please let me know what the problem is?

Comment: Finally worked With this Change, we need to pass the rest template to check the health    ```@Bean
    public ServiceInstanceListSupplier serviceInstanceListSupplier(
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        return ServiceInstanceListSupplier.builder()
                .withHints()
                .withBlockingDiscoveryClient()
                .withBlockingHealthChecks(new RestTemplate())
                .build(context);
    }```

Comment: My experience is that this error occurs because the health check fails - if you debug the code of withBlockingHealthChecks() you will see the check fail and the above error logged. It would really useful if the failed health check was logged too but it isn't.